# how to separate layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I not really sure how to describe correctly my problem. My layout contains a top menu with linearlayout, and below it is a tablelayout that is wrapped with a scrollview. My problem is when I scroll up, the content tablelayout moves up and blocks the top menu view. So could anyone know how to solve the problem please point me. Thanks

This is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/menu_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_bar" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/myTableLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set your ScrollView to be below your LinearLayout, else it stacks on it.

Hope this helps!